# Passing ID between two Model or Razor Pages

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new to Core and razor programming and in my project I have to add a user to the _Context then pass the ID of the added us

```
_Context.StaffMember.Add(StaffMember);
            await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();

            Id = StaffMember.UserId;
            return RedirectToPage("./Invite", Id);
```

When I tested the code, I can see the ID correctly, but it is not getting passed to the other page

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id){}
```

and the id is null.
I tried the asp-route-id="Model.Id" on the user page, but it is not working.

```
<input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-id="Model.Id"/>
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution

```
return RedirectToPage("./Invite", new { id = Id})
```